# How can I fix "Not allowed to load local resource" error in microsoft edge or google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console, microsoft-edge

I am trying to link an external javascript file to my HTML file. But as soon as I run it my console shows this error "Not allowed to load local resource". I read about its cause but can anyone help me with how to fix this?

my statement:

"
"

I have tried using a static web server extension in Chrome but it's not working.

Comment: Please show the essential parts of the code you're trying to run

Comment: <script src="index.js" defer> </script>

Comment: I tried it linking in my HTML boilerplate just after the title tag. but on atom live server and in browsers the console is reflecting the above-mentioned error.. I read about this error and came to know that it is related to web security in browsers. But I don't know how to fix it and test my index.js file in console.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to debugging code, opening it from disk by "double clicking" the HTML file is rarely a good idea. Try using a local server instead. There are a lot of great ones available. I don't know what IDE you are using, but VSCode has Live Server for example which works great, or you can use XAMPP as a standalone solution.

Comment: I am using atom-live-server and it is working fine for my HTML and CSS files but I am facing this issue when I try to add an external JS file to my code.

Comment: Interesting. And you made sure to use relative paths for everything you load?

Comment: yes I tried it with both full path and relative path

Comment: I tried to find Its solution but the only answer I got was " Modern browsers don't allow to load files from local resources due to security concerns ". But I don't know how to practice or implement my js code if it won't allow me to do so. So, if anyone uses something else as its alternative or if someone can solve my problem do let me know. I am struck in my course due to this error.

Comment: As I've mentioned I use VS Code's Live Server extension for quite some time now. It works great, give it a try!

Comment: sure, I will try that out

Comment: I tried using VS code's Live Server extension as well. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/90.0.4430.93/Extensions/js/oops.js

Comment: Please link a repo to your code so I can better help diagnose the problem

Comment: I tried using a relative path in VS code and it worked...Thanks for the help Richard... one more thing is I want to go back in my path from my current project folder what shout be the syntax of my path.   for eg I have a folder containing 3 folders (HTML, CSS, js) and HTML folder is my current project folder then how can I add relative path of files in my js folder or css folder?

Comment: In that case you can still use relative paths. Let's say you have an index.html in HTML folder and want to access index.css in the CSS folder. You can then write `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/index.css">`. The `..` of course means step back one folder in the hierarchy.

Comment: "I tried using a relative path in VS code and it worked...Thanks for the help Richard...". Glad I could be of help in this case, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Don't enter full path of image..
Example: **DO NOT ENTER LIKE THIS** : C:\Users\A1\Desktop\vs\images\cloud.png
**Enter LIKE THIS** : iamges\cloud.png
just ensure that your folder named images is inside your project folder

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it's easy to apply I used to use this path to bind js file with HTML file without a live server
C:\User\Usu\Desktop\Michael\CursoScript\JavaScript\Curso.js but when I started to use a extension live server the console always show up this message "Not allowed to load local resource" so I changed the path to
/JavaScript/Curso.js and it worked.

Espero les ayude a que lea sus archivos JavaScript.

[Here you can see how I have ordenated my files and folders and the two examples the first onw doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C2BM.png)

Comment: please edit your question and replace the image link by the actual code. And maybe you can replace the spanish by the english translation....